# Why does the sed command skip some lines in bash?

Tags: bash, csv, sed

I have a `csv` file whose top looks like this:

```
s_m_title
,,
7988114_lig2
7988114_lig2
7988114_lig3
7988114_lig2
7982570_lig2
7982570_lig2
9081391_lig2
9081391_lig2
6555615_lig
7988114_lig2
```

I want to remove every line that doesn't start with numbers. I then ran this `sed` command to print every row containing a number to a new `csv` file.

`sed -n -e '/1/{p;n;}' -e '/2/{p;n;}' -e '/3/{p;n;}' -e '/4/{p;n;}' -e '/5/{p;n;}' -e '/6/{p;n;}' -e '/7/{p;n;}' -e '/8/{p;n;}' -e '/9/{p;n;}'  test_all.csv > improved2.csv`

The top of that new `csv` file looks like this:

```
7988114_lig2
7988114_lig2
7988114_lig3
7988114_lig2
7982570_lig2
7982570_lig2
9081391_lig2
9081391_lig2
7988114_lig2
```

The `sed` command correctly removed the `s_m_title` and `,,` line, but it also removed the `6555615_lig` line. Why?

I figured out that if I do this as two commands,

`sed '/,,/d' test_all.csv > improved3.csv`

`sed '/s_m_title/d' improved3.csv > improved2.csv`

I get the correct output without any of the numbered lines being removed. So why does this usage of `sed` remove some of the numbered lines?

Comment: because to print 1st line you need `/s_m_title/{n;p}` or `1p`  or `/s_m_title/p` , none of your regex is matched to `s_m_title`. With that said, I do not understand why you are doing this, but I am sure there could be a shorter way of doing what you did, if you say the logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just trying to echo the lines that start with numbers, you could use this:

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]/p' test_all.csv
```

Or just grep:

```
grep '^[0-9]' test_all.csv
```

---

The behavior you're seeing with sed is caused by your use of the `n` command -- which moves to the next line of input -- when you're in the middle of executing commands.

1. Sed reads your first line of input [s_m_title], no commands match, so it echoes nothing (because of the `-n` option) and moves to the next line of text.
2. It reads the second line [,,]. Ditto.
3. It reads the third line [7988114_lig2], which matches the pattern of your first command [/1/], so it executes that command by printing the line and moving to the next line of input [7988114_lig2], but it stays at the current place in your list of commands. So now it compares the new line of input with the pattern of the second command [/2/]... and so on.

It just so happens that when it reads the line with 6555615_lig, it's already deep into your list of commands, past the /6/ pattern. And since the line fails to match any remaining commands [/7/, /8/, and /9/], sed reaches the end of the commands, echoes nothing for that line of input, gets the next line of input [7988114_lig2], and starts over with the first command.

Comment: Is this command working when numbers are present in those lines which starts with characters or special symbols?

Comment: Initially I thought the original poster wanted lines that contain numbers, but I've updated my answer to keep only the lines that _start_ with numbers.

Answer (score 3):

It prints only those lines that starts with any number between 0-9

```
sed '/^[0-9]/!d' filename.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you want to print any line with a 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9 in it. In that case:

```
sed -n '/[1-9]/p' test_all.csv
```

Or:

```
sed '/[1-9]/!d' test_all.csv
```

Alternatively, to print all *except* the first two lines, use:

```
sed '1,2d' test_all.csv
```

Or:

```
sed -n '3,$p' test_all.csv
```